# android find correct phone number

Tags: android, android-contacts

Given a phone number as string, how do I find the correct value of it as stored in contacts?

Example:
Given Phone number: 9743343954
Phone number in contacts: +919743343954

Edit: The length of the numbers isn't fixed.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're happy with one of the answers below, please do remember to accept it! It encourages people to provide answers :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean but maybe this will help you:

```
    //Find contact by given number
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode("9743343954"));
    String[] projection = new String[] { PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.NORMALIZED_NUMBER };
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {// while(c.moveToNext()){
        //get number assigned by user to given contact, in this case 9743343954
        String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup.NUMBER));
        //get normalized E164 number, in this case +919743343954
        String normalized = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup.NORMALIZED_NUMBER));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Number: " + number + "; normalized: " + normalized,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    c.close();
```

To make this works add permission to project manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your example, the phone number is of length 10 characters, in contacts it is 13, and you want the last 10 of those to match. So, something like:

```
// I am assuming that you've removed all spaces, full stops,
// dashes etc from the two input variables
public boolean numbersMatch(String numberToMatch, String numberFromContacts) {
    // Ensure that the both numbers are of a reasonable length
    if (numberToMatch.length() < 9) return false;
    if (numberFromContacts.length() < 9) return false;

    // Is the number to match hidden in the contacts number
    if (numberFromContacts.lastIndexOf(numberToMatch) != -1) return true;

    // Or is the contact number hidden in the number to macth
    if (numberToMatch.lastIndexOf(numberFromContacts) != -1) return true;

    // No match, so return false
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do this

Assume the phone number given is

```
String a = "9123456789";
```

And the one in contacts is

```
String b = "+91-9123456789";
```

Then you can easily check it this way

```
if(b.contains(a))
{
//Do what you want!
}
```

Comment: And what if I have a number "+91-9123456789" and a short local one "234567"? They have to be different.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Lecho seems is good if you want to get the associated contact (or related information). More information on this page from android doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html

As far as I know, PhoneLookup.NORMALIZED_NUMBER is available since API 16.

On the other side, if you want to compare 2 numbers to see if they are the same but formated in two different ways you can use :

```
PhoneNumberUtils.compare(phoneNumber1, phoneNumber2)
```

Best,

Answer (score -1):

First step would be to remove all extra spaces and extra characters:

```
//Removes the extra characters from the incoming number
    private String removeExtraCharacters(String phoneNumber){
        try
        {
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("(", "");
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(")", "");
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("-", "");
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(" ", "");
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("+", "");

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e("Cal Reciever_R", e.toString());
        }
        return phoneNumber;
    }
```

Now you can use the substring method to get 10 digit number and ignorin the +91 from front as follows:

```
phoneNumber =phoneNumber .substring(phoneNumber .length()-10);
```